# [Advanced Installer]How to add a default directory after selecting a new directory?

Tags: advanced-installer

When I select a new directory, how can I add a default directory to the selected directory. For example: defult path is C:\Program Files\myFile, alter select d:\ the directory is d:. i want to add the default path like d:\myFile?

Answer (score 0):

The default installation path can be configured in Install Parameters view of your setup project. Just set the default path in Application Folder field.